# Where does `powercfg` get battery health information, and why isn't it in WMI?

Tags: windows, powershell, battery, wmi, powercfg

On Windows 10 (among other versions) running on a device having a battery, I can use `powercfg /batteryreport` to obtain the "Design Capacity" and "Last Full Charge Capacity" for the battery, which give an idea of the remaining useful service life of the battery and how much its capacity has degraded from use.

```
C:\Users\superuser\AppData\Local\Temp>powercfg /batteryreport
Battery life report saved to C:\Users\superuser\AppData\Local\Temp\battery-report.html
```

The HTML report is generated instantaneously and displays, among others, the statistics I'm interested in:

[image: powercfg battery report showing design capacity and full charge capacity]

Moreover, I can boot into this laptop's built-in diagnostic environment and it displays similar figures, and the discharge cycle count of the battery.

**From where are these values being obtained?** I would like to be able to track this battery life data over time for a fleet of laptops, preferably from a Powershell script. It seemed likely that this data should be in WMI, and sure enough, there's a [Win32_Battery class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394074(v=vs.85).aspx) having `DesignCapacity` and `FullChargeCapacity` fields, but on all the systems I have tested, they are undefined:

```
PS C:\Users\superuser> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Battery | Select-Object -Property *Capacity | Format-List


DesignCapacity     :
FullChargeCapacity :
```

There must be some programmatic way to access this information, because `powercfg` is doing it. If there is some WMI, .NET, or Powershell way to do this, I'd like to know about it. I could generate the `powercfg` report and then parse it, but I really don't want to implement an ugly workaround when there is most likely a "right" way to do it that is just escaping me.

Comment: well, the windows is able to retrieve that information from the system firmware (BIOS/UEFI) via the ACPI: http://www.acpi.info/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface

Comment: +1 good question. I hate it when stuff isn't in WMI or not wrapped by PowerShell.

Comment: This capitalization trend is getting ridiculous. LION CHEMISTRY!

Comment: Ah, the "CHEMISTRY" in the HTML reports (black boxes) say LION, presumably referring to Lithium Ion.  It took me a while to comprehend just what @beatcracker's comment was saying.

Comment: @TOOGAM So, it's just me, then :). Still, I want a RACOON CHEMISTRY in my laptop battery, so it would grab whatever power source it could find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you have to dig into [MSBattery super class](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/powershell/rootwmimsbatteryclass/):

> A number of the classes in root\wmi return results from more than one
>   class. That sounds odd but it can be explained by an example.
>
> The namespace contains a number of classes related to the battery in
>   laptops
>
> ```
> gwmi -Namespace root\wmi -List *battery*
>
> MSBatteryClassEvent
> BatteryStatusChange
> BatteryTagChange 
> MSBatteryClass
> BatteryStaticData
> BatteryRuntime
> BatteryCycleCount 
> BatteryTemperature
> BatteryStatus
> BatteryFullChargedCapacity
> ```
>
> We’ll ignore the event and change classes for now.  If we pick out the
>   MSBattery class we get information from a number of other classes
>   returned – MSBattery is a super class.
>
> ```
> PS> gwmi -Namespace root\wmi -Class MSBatteryClass | select __class
>
> __CLASS  ——-
> BatteryCycleCount
> BatteryFullChargedCapacity
> BatteryStaticData
> BatteryRuntime BatteryStatus
> ```

Examples, that kind of work on my laptop:

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'root\wmi' -Query 'select DeviceName, ManufactureName, Chemistry, DesignedCapacity from BatteryStaticData'

__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : BatteryStaticData
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : 
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 4
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
Chemistry        : 1852787020
DesignedCapacity : 48400
DeviceName       : K52F-44
ManufactureName  : ASUSTek
PSComputerName   : 


Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'root\wmi'  -Query 'select FullChargedCapacity  from BatteryFullChargedCapacity'

__GENUS             : 2
__CLASS             : BatteryFullChargedCapacity
__SUPERCLASS        : 
__DYNASTY           : 
__RELPATH           : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT    : 1
__DERIVATION        : {}
__SERVER            : 
__NAMESPACE         : 
__PATH              : 
FullChargedCapacity : 47157
PSComputerName      : 


Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'root\wmi'  -Query 'select CycleCount from BatteryCycleCount'

__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : BatteryCycleCount
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : 
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
CycleCount       : 0
PSComputerName   :
```

Why kind of? Because while you can see that `DesignedCapacity`,  `FullChargedCapacity` and `CycleCount` have some values, `powercfg /batteryreport` doesnt recoginze them:

[image: Battery stats]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple WMI "crawler" that combines all battery-classes into one object:

```
# get battery-identifier:
$batteryClass = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\WMI -Class MSBatteryClass
if (!$batteryClass) {'this device has no physical battery.'; break}
$batteryData = foreach ($entry in $batteryClass) {
    if ($entry.UniqueID) {$entry | select UniqueID, InstanceName}
}

# find data based on the UniqueID of the battery:
foreach ($entry in Get-wmiobject Win32_battery) {
    $battery = @($batteryData).where{$_.UniqueID -eq $entry.DeviceID}
    $attribs = $entry | Get-Member | ?{$_.MemberType -eq 'Property' -and !$_.name.startswith('__')}
    foreach ($a in $attribs.name) {
        $battery | Add-Member -Name "Win32_battery.$a" -Value $entry.$a -MemberType NoteProperty
    }
}

# find data based on the InstanceName of the battery:
foreach ($class in $batteryClass.__CLASS | select -Unique) {
    $classData = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\WMI -Class $class
    foreach ($entry in $classData) {
        $battery = @($batteryData).where{$_.InstanceName -eq $entry.InstanceName}
        $attribs = $entry | Get-Member | ?{$_.MemberType -eq 'Property' -and !$_.name.startswith('__')}
        foreach ($a in $attribs.name) {
            $battery | Add-Member -Name "$class.$a" -Value $entry.$a -MemberType NoteProperty
        }
    }
}

$battery
```

Unfortunaltely the WMI-classes do not translate all values into readable format (e.g. chemistry is just a value but not a string) and also not any runtime estimation for the fully charged battery. That one comes from the history of all charg/discharge events into the powercfg-report.

Comment: You verified these examples worked within a VM?

Comment: VMs dont have a physical battery and no class "MS_battery". I added one line for error-handling in the snippet.